# Why isn't the payment method showing on the frontend in Magento 2?

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.1.6, checkout-page

The issue is that I have enabled cash on delivery and some other payment methods from the backend. But it is not showing on the frontend.

I recently created a new theme and removed some CSS and JS from checkout pages by adding code lines in `/app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Checkout/layout/*.xml` files. Does that effect on it.

I have updated head section.Here is the code which changed.

```
<head>
    <!-- Remove local resources -->
    <remove src="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <remove src="css/style_new.css"/>
    <remove src="css/animate.min.css"/>
    <remove src="js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
    <remove src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"/>
    <remove src="js/wow.min.js"/>

</head>
```

Can any one suggest me solution to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

changing the checkout layout can definetly result in something like that. Could you add these changes to your question?

you might have accidently overwritten sth that is important for the payment method rendering

Comment: i have updated my question. Can you please let me know which XML is rendering the  payment method on checkout page?